# update IP Address in Vagrant VMs

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I have 5 VMs that I spin up using vagrant.

**3** load Balancers, and **2** web servers.

---

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define "lb0" do |lb0|
    lb0.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb0.vm.hostname = "lb0"
    lb0.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.50"
  end
  config.vm.define "lb01" do |lb01|
    lb01.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb01.vm.hostname = "lb01"
    lb01.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.51"
  end
  config.vm.define "lb02" do |lb02|
    lb02.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb02.vm.hostname = "lb02"
    lb02.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.52"
  end

  config.vm.define "web01" do |web01|
    web01.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web01.vm.hostname = "web01"
    web01.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.53"
  end

  config.vm.define "web02" do |web02|
    web02.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web02.vm.hostname = "web02"
    web02.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.54"
  end
end
```

---

I just recently updated the IPs of my load balancers from `10.11.12.x` --> `10.11.13.x` due to the new requirement.

---

I run `vagrant up` again, I **don't** see new IPs updated on my `lb0`, `lb1`, and `lb2`. :(  Did I miss anything ?

---

What do I do to update my existing VMs IP **without** having to destroy them and recreate them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adjusting the new IP in **Vagrantfile**

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define "lb0" do |lb0|
    lb0.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb0.vm.hostname = "lb0"
    lb0.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.50"
  end
  config.vm.define "lb01" do |lb01|
    lb01.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb01.vm.hostname = "lb01"
    lb01.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.51"
  end
  config.vm.define "lb02" do |lb02|
    lb02.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb02.vm.hostname = "lb02"
    lb02.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.52"
  end

  config.vm.define "web01" do |web01|
    web01.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web01.vm.hostname = "web01"
    web01.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.53"
  end

  config.vm.define "web02" do |web02|
    web02.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web02.vm.hostname = "web02"
    web02.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.54"
  end
end
```

I've learn that I have to run `vagrant reload`

Then, I noticed my IP are updated as expected.

Comment: this is still weird : vagrant reload = vagrant halt + vagrant up - as you said you still did not see the IP updated after you run vagrant up again, so it should have already worked after you stopped and restarted

Comment: I didn't stop the VMs. I forgot to run vagrant halt. I'm not aware of that back then.

Comment: oh ok makes sense then ... up will boot the VM; if you make change to vagrantfile you need halt + up or reload (which is halt + up)

Answer (score 1):

This is weird, normally if you change the network configuration from the Vagrantfile, vagrant should update accordingly in your VM.

If you enable something like `config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.13.52"` you should see at the end of file `/etc/network/interfaces` something like

```
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 10.11.13.52
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

If you do not see your updated IP in the file, change it manually and run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` to have the new IP available

Answer (score 1):

Update your Vagrantfile with the ip address available and `vagrant reload` to effect the changes.